# Data from API service is not updating, only updating after celaring cache

Tags: java, android, api, service

This is my code to get data from API Service. but, when I update data from server, data in the app is not updating. but if I go to setting app then do a clear cache and open my app then data is update. what i should do ?

```
private void callDataPekerjaan() {
    listPekerjaan.clear();

    JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url1,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, response.toString());

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            DataPekerjaan item = new DataPekerjaan();

                            item.setId(obj.getString(TAG_ID_PEKERJAAN));
                            item.setNama(obj.getString(TAG_PEKERJAAN));

                            listPekerjaan.add(item);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    adapterpekerjaan.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    hideDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(DataMasyarakat1Activity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jArr);
}
```

Comment: where you are setting your adapter to listview in your code? that may be the problem

Answer (score 0):

It may be issue with Caching with Volley, Try putting this piece of code  in volley

```
 @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
                requestQueue.getCache().clear();
            }
```